# Handling separate Bundle Requirements on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, composer-php

I'm trying to develop a re-usable bundle for Symfony, but I'm stuck, as I don't understand how to migrate from the bundle itself for a package.

I've found this very usefull tutorial:

http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package

But unfortunately, it's only usefull when you already have your library finished.

What I would like to do is being able to, for example, create a new symfony bundle in a project, and to define what dependencies that bundle have, let's say at a composer.json file under the root of that bundle (and not the whole project) and, when doing composer update at the root of my project, it automatically handles the deps for the bundle AND the rest of the project.

Then, when I see that the bundle is fully functional, I would then, of course, upload it to github and packagist and, therefore, the tutorial would be useful.

Has anyone deal with this kind of issues?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't really get your problem: you can define the dependencies of your app in the `composer.json` file in your application. You will as well find the same file in every bundle.

Comment: The idea is:

I have a composer.json at my root project, and then at MyProject/src/MyBundle, I have an other composer.json that should be used to install vendors at MyProject/vendor. 

As it is right now, I I define a composer.json at a bundle, It does not automatically install the vendors required for that bundle.. And that's what I want.

Comment: @pmartelletti Does your main `composer.json` reference your bundle as a dependency? If not, and you just added it to your vendor directory, obviously Composer won't know to load transitive dependencies for you. If, however, your bundle is in the `composer.json` of your application, then this works just fine

Comment: Right now, I have my bundle under the src/ directory, where all bundle are by default in symfony. What I want, is to define a list of packages that my bundle require in order to work properly and to able to reference that composer.json file (that is under src/mybundle) from the main composer.json file, under the root directory.

Is that possible?

Comment: @pmartelletti That is not how you'd write a reusable bundle. Bundles under `src/` are considered application specific and thus use the `composer.json` of the application. They don't have their own `composer.json` file (it would be pointless, really). In order for your `composer.json` in your bundle directory to be used, the bundle itself has to be required by _your application's_ `composer.json` (meaning it will be loaded into the `vendor` directory).

Comment: So, If at the moment I'm developing the bundle, it's not finished.. Where should I place it? Under vendor directory and making composer.json require it?

If that's the case... how would I require a bundle like that in my composer? What type of repository would you define?

Comment: @pmartelletti Well, do you really need to worry about it at all right now? Continue developing the application (taking note of the dependencies you're using right now that work). When you're done you can worry about packaging it with the right dependencies. Right now it's probably not necessary.

Comment: If the bundle you are building is kind of generic (not a final app) you should probably write it to be inside the vendor folder (git + packagist is the easy way to do) and simply have an app mockup in `src` using this bundle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop and include a Composer package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295558/how-to-develop-and-include-a-composer-package)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local repository as a requirement for your app:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type":"vcs",
        "url":"/home/marek/dev/sf2-bundles/TheodoRogerCmsBundle"
    }
],
"require":{
     "theodo/roger-cms-bundle":"dev-master"
}
```

Source: http://marekkalnik.tumblr.com/post/22929686367/composer-installing-package-from-local-git-repository

Then you can put it anywhere you prefer and Composer will fetch it for your app.